# Particular line match in Regex Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Input:

```
gis.google.com
CAT
DOG
gis1.goole.com
CAT gis.google.com
gis.google.com DOG
```

I have used below regex to match the prticlar pattern per line.

```
/^[\w]+\s+[\w]+[\.][\w]+[\.][\w]+$/mg
```

It is matching below

```
DOG
gis1.goole.com
CAT gis.google.com
```

But I wanted to match only one line

```
   CAT gis.google.com
```

Please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\s+` with `\h+` where `\s` would match spaces plus newline characters also but `\h` only matches the horizontal spaces. That's the reason why the consecutive two lines (DoG and it's following line) got matched. And also remove all the unnecessary character classes from your regex.

```
^\w+\h+\w+\.\w+\.\w+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1hY1/1)

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the regex?

It could be simplified a little, but it works when done using line by line processing:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print if /^\w+\s+\w+[.]\w+[.]\w+$/;
}

__DATA__
gis.google.com
CAT
DOG
gis1.goole.com
CAT gis.google.com
gis.google.com DOG
```

Outputs:

```
CAT gis.google.com
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/2QGm3g)</kbd>